# Databinding in recyclerview using kotlin causing issue

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

Here is my app-level gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding  = true
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
    correctErrorTypes = true
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "${buildDir}/generated/source/kapt/main"
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/test/java'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2.0-alpha10"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
    //glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

this is my main gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.10"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement databinding in recyclerview using kotlin. But it is giving me runtime error

Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

Anyone has faced the same error? I have searched and gone through many links related to this error but all states the use of room library which I am not using and still getting this error.
Any help is much appreicated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error after updating my
Android studio to

> Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 3

and also updated

> gradle version to 7.0.3

and

> kotlin plugin update to 1.5.20.

Basically I updated all my resources and the error was solved.

Updated gradle files

app-level gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.navigationdemoapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.0-beta02"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.0-beta02"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

project level gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.20"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
     
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
buildFeatures {
        dataBinding  = true
    }
```

Try this

```
buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true //<--- for binding the data 
        viewBinding true //<-- for binding the view 

    }
```

Comment: It didn't worked when I updated my code according to your suggestion. It is giving me the same error.